# Cardinality of a set of functions from $\mathbb N$ to a set of real numbers

Tags: cardinals

Let $S$ be the set of functions from $\mathbb N$ to the set $\{\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}\}$. Determine $|S|$.

I understand how to prove the converse case where $T$ is the set of functions from $\{\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}\}$ to $\mathbb N$ by defining a bijective function $f:T \to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$, where $|\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \times \mathbb N| = |\mathbb N|$. How would I approach this case though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know how to calculate the cardinality of all $0$-$1$ sequences?

Comment: Would that mean defining a bijective function $f:$ $S$ $\to$ $[0, 1]$ x $[0, 1]$ x $[0, 1]$ x $[0, 1]$?

Comment: Well, by $ 0 -1 $ sequences I mean functions from $ \mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$. It's easier to count them, but once you have done that, it should be easier to do your task

Comment: $ \textbf{Hint:}$ every real number has its binary representation

Comment: I think I understand it now. |S| = |P($\mathbb N$)| = |$\mathbb R$|?

Comment: That's correct.